# NodeJS & Sequelize: showing all the conversation the current user has

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i am currently trying to implement my backend from my all conversations screen. i am finding all the conversations and including all the messages associated with each conversation.

In my react native frontend, in my all conversations screen, i am showing all the conversations as a flatlist and showing the last message sent between the 2 users by picking it out from the list of messages.

Should i continue using this approach or will it be better in terms of performance to include a link to the last message in Conversation table and update it every time a new message is sent in the conversation? If so, how do i change my code to do so?

Conversation Model:

```
const Conversation = db.define("Conversation", {},
{
paranoid: true, 
timestamps: true, 
deletedAt: "deletedAt",
}
);

module.exports = Conversation;

User.hasMany(Conversation, {
foreignKey: 'user1'
});

User.hasMany(Conversation, {
foreignKey: 'user2'
});

Conversation.belongsTo(User, { as: 'Creator', foreignKey: 'user1', allowNull: false })
Conversation.belongsTo(User, { as: 'Recipient', foreignKey: 'user2', allowNull: false })
```

Message Model:

```
const Message = db.define("Message", {
senderId: {
type: Sequelize.STRING,
},
receiverId: {
type: Sequelize.STRING,
},
message: {
type: Sequelize.STRING,
},
conversationId:{
type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
}
});

module.exports = Message;

User.hasMany(Message, {
foreignKey: 'senderId',
});

User.hasMany(Message, {
foreignKey: 'receiverId',
});

  Message.associate = (models) => {
  Message.belongsTo(models.Conversations,{
  foreignKey: "conversationId",
  }
  ); 
  };

Conversation.hasMany(Message,{
foreignKey: "conversationId",
}
);

Message.belongsTo(User, {
as:"Sender",
foreignKey: "senderId",
allowNull: false 
});

Message.belongsTo(User, {
as:"Receiver",
foreignKey: "receiverId",
allowNull: false 
});
```

Get All Conversations Query:

```
router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
const conversations = await Conversation.findAll({
  order: [[Message,"createdAt", "DESC"]],
  include: [
    {
    model: Message,
    where: {
      [Op.or]: [
        { senderId: req.user.id }, 
        { receiverId: req.user.id },
      ],
    },
    required: true, // RIGHT  JOIN
  }]
  })
 

if (!conversations) return res.status(404).send();

    res.status(200).send();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the conversations and messages into the local database
using sqlite of the mobile device.

To do so, you don't have to query whole conversation for every login.
Meta data table can be even helpful to relieve the server stress

I suggest you to use sqlite in RN and add meta table in remote database.

---

#### Pattern.

1. Load Conversations from remote database with the count of messages when logining in.
   ( If meta data table exists, this part will be faster and lighter )
2. When displaying the conversions, use the lastest data in local database.
3. Comparing count of messages, if count is different, you can assume that user in this device didn't check the lastest message. So Render badge component to notify user that he or she didn't read it yet.
4. When user enter the conversation, fetch messages and store it into local database of the device.

---

Socket io part
Brief concept is like this.

ref. https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-api/#socket-on-eventName-callback

#### Client

```js
    const [ conversations, setConversations ] = useState([])
    const [ syncState, setSyncState ] = useState(false)
    const [ socket, setSocket ] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() =>{
    ...
    // you might wanna set conversation from local database here
    ...

    io.on('connection', soc => {
        soc.join("your room")
        ...
        socket.on('synced', data =>{
           //mapNewDataToConversationState
           ...
           setSynced(true)
        })
        setSocket(soc)
      })
    
    ...
    }, [ ... ])
     

    useEffect(() =>{//when loaded and socked established
      if(!socket) return
      if(syncState) return
      socket.emit('sync', { data : conversation })
    }, [ socket ])
```

#### Server

```js
//let say you already set app.io as socket io connection
//add a event listener for client sync

socket.on('sync', async conversation =>{
   const responseData = {}

   for(const c of conversation){
      const lastestMsg = c.Message[c.Message.length - 1]
      
      const messages = await Message.findAll({
        where : {
        ...//Maybe greater than createdAt, any cursor attribute in here
        }
      })

      responseData[c.id] = messages
   }

   socket.emit('synced', responseData )

})
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for getting back to me. I am currently using Postgres in my backend. How do i use local database sqlite?

Comment: What I'm suggesting you to use sqlite is not for backend storage bro. you can start the sqlite for RN. Check out, https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage

Comment: is it the same concept as asyncStorage?

Comment: I don't know about the asyncStorage. So I looked it up, https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage. I think you're right since Android is using the asyncStorage as RocksDB and Sqlite.

Comment: If you're using socket io, the solution can be easier I guess

Comment: the main difference between sqlite and asyncstorage is that sqlite is useful if you want to execute relational data while asyncstorage is useful for storing an array of objects in the cache and retrieve it later on.

Comment: I am actually doing all of that so i can enable socket.io to allow 2 users to have a conversation with each other. But i am still new to sokcet.io hence do not know how to accomplish so

Comment: Thanks for the datails. I learned a lot from that.

Comment: Back to the topic, I think you can load cached data from the local database since you already have a client for it(=asyncStorage). Listen 'join:room' event then compare the local data and database reponse like `if(localDB.room.message.length != remoteDB.response.rows.length) const newMessages = await Message.findAll({ where : { createdAt : { [Op.gt] : lastedMessage.createdAt } }, { conversationId : cachedConversation.id } })`

Comment: Do you have any experience with socket.io?

Comment: I have, but not in production. I think I'm not so good for helping you with details.

Comment: Can you give me a brief idea on how it works?

Comment: Well, If I were you, I'm gonna sync asyncStorage data with redux in main page using hook.

`useEffect((() =>{/* sorry bro, never used asyncStorage */}), [ location ])`

then when socket io client establish the connection. Sync asyncStorage and the remove database you can find the event list in socket io github.

Comment: i mean can you give me a brief on how sockets.io works?

Comment: since this is too long for comment, I edit my answer. You can use this concept but not sure the details since I just write the code with API documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to limit included messages in each conversation to the last message only

```
const conversations = await Conversation.findAll({
  order: [[Message,"createdAt", "DESC"]],
  include: [
    {
    model: Message,
    order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
    limit: 1,
    where: {
      [Op.or]: [
        { senderId: req.user.id }, 
        { receiverId: req.user.id },
      ],
    },
    required: true, // RIGHT  JOIN
  }]
  })
```

If the above query doesn't work you can always try to store the last message id in a conversation but this can lead to inconsistencies if you store a message and forget to update a link to the last message in a conversation or you delete the last message and again forget to update the link in a conversation.

Comment: Hi Anatoly, i tried the query above and got this error (node:35418) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: missing FROM-clause entry for table "Messages"

Comment: Order statement can only be in top level of query model. To work with this, delete the inside order statement ant limit, move limit statemet outside of inlcude

Comment: Move conditions about sender and receiver to Conversation, turn off `required`, add `separate: true` to `include` option

Comment: @hellikiam moving `limit` to the options will limit conversations and not messages!

Comment: @Anatoly That's so true. but still order cannot be used in this one right? I mean, in the include

Comment: Why not? At least this option exists in Typescript IncludeOptions type though it is not among options in the official documentation. @kd12345 I recommend to try `order` inside `include` option and see how it goes (maybe you should add generated SQL query that way we can see if a query is correct or not)

Comment: When i move where conditions from include to conversation i get an error because senderId is not a column in conversation only in messages. Also, when i move order from conversation to include it does not work.

Comment: Of course you need to rename `senderId` and `receiverId` into `user1` and `user2` if you move conditions

Comment: Can you show a SQL query when `order` is moved into `include`?